# Rxjs subscribe not called after adding retryWhen()

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

here is my code which is giving me issue.

```
  gotoGoogle() {
    let obs = this.httpCtrl.get("https://www.google.com/", {observe : "response", responseType : "text"}).pipe(tap(() => console.log("Http GET method executed")),
    map(res => {
        console.log("The res status from GET is: ", res.status)
        console.log("The res from map is: ", res)
}),
    retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors.pipe(delayWhen(() => timer(2000)),
        tap(() => console.log("Retrying immediately..."))
        );
    })).subscribe((res : any) => {
      console.log("Status from gotoGoogle(): ", res);
    })
  }
```

I am following a tutorial online and the code looks like this. The code also compiled fine. When I open Console and ran this function. I noticed that the `console.log("Status from gotoGoogle(): ", res);` is an "undefined". 
But the `console.log("The res status from GET is: ", res.status) and console.log("The res from map is: ", res)` does return with status code 200 and the appropriate reply. What could be the issue with the "subscribe" method? Thank you.

Comment: replace map with tap, you need to return value from map

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, such an oversight on my part...

Comment: To explain, return type of tap operator is void. It should be the terminating operator  in a stream. Use it when you don't want to return response.